# Calculate pm2 ram consumption on basis of hit or traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, loopback, pm2

I have deployed loopback backend application in ec2 instance. I am using Pm2 server. How can I calculate ram and cpu for traffic or hit ?

Answer (score 1):

With EC2 you don’t have to make it right from the start because it’s easy to change the instance size later.

For start make a guess - e.g. new project may be ok with *t3.small*, moderately busy site may do for example with *m5.large*, etc. Once it’s up and running monitor the CPU and memory utilisation in *CloudWatch* and if the chosen instance type was too big for your needs downsize it, if it’s too small make it bigger. It’s easy.

Better yet deploy your app in *Auto Scaling Group* that will automatically adjust the number of running instances based on the traffic. That way you don’t have to pay for over-provisioned resources.

Hope that helps :)